# Trouble with filters and triggers in dc.js - re-drawing is out of sync

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

I have two plots: a line plot and a bubble plot. When I click on the bubble plot, I want the line plot to be updated so that it is drawn with only the data related to that 'bubble'. This is different from the standard implementation whereby clicking would add or remove the data from the existing filter.

[image]

If you look at the image you can see that although 'model 0' is selected the plotted hazard (y-scale in plot 1) does not correspond.

[image]

And now when I click on 'model 5', I get the opposite.

My current implementation is posted as a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/drstevok/2Hmya/3/). I can see from the attached data table that I am achieving what I want, but the line plot does not re-draw correctly. In fact, it seems to re-draw with the *last* filter, not the new one.

This implementation is hacked from [here](https://becomingadatascientist.wordpress.com/tag/crossfilter-js/): in particular, the  `renderlet` and `on("filtered", function (chart) {` lines. However, to make this work, I have had to comment out the `plot1.filter(chart.filter());` line for the second plot.

I don't really understand why a `renderlet` *and* the `on("filtered" ...` or `on("postRedraw" ...` listeners are needed together.

I have been round the houses on this one, so any suggestions would be very gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to simplify the jsfiddle to isolate the problem.  Here is the adapted jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/mKz7A/

Your plot2 keyAccessor accessed the df value from the p.value.df rather than using a dimension on df.  My guess is that this is what was causing problems.  Here is the adapted code:

```
dfDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.df;});
...
plot2.width(300)
     .height(250)
     .dimension(dfDim)
```

I also noticed that your plot2 valueAccessor and radiusAccessor were not using a computed average.  Your code would overwrite est and estse for each record added or removed from the group.  Here is the adapted code that computes the average:

```
dfGroup = dfDim.group().reduce(
       //add
       function (p, v) {
           ++p.count;
           p.est += v.est;
           p.avg_est = p.est / p.count;
           p.estse += v.estse;
           p.avg_estse = p.estse / p.count;
           return p;
       },
       //remove
       function (p, v) {
           --p.count;
           p.est -= v.est;
           p.avg_est = p.est / p.count;
           p.estse -= v.estse;
           p.avg_estse = p.estse / p.count;
           return p;
       },
       //init
       function (p, v) {
           return {
               count: 0,
               est: 0,
               estse: 0,
               avg_est: 0,
               avg_estse: 0
           };
       });
```

After these changes, I believe the code behaves as you wanted.

Comment: Appreciate this. Have not had chance to check but will review, re-post, and accept asap